# Deploy rails app at sub uri of a domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, production, puma

We have set up a production server for our rails app with Nginx and puma. We want to deploy our rails app at sub uri and on main domain we want to put wordpress for home page, pricing page etc.

How we configure our rails that it able to run on sub uri which have Devise gem as authentication. Will we need to change our routes for sub uri?

What will be the configuration for nginx and puma?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First put your desired sub uri path in `application.rb` i.e. ***main***

```
...
config.relative_url_root = "/main"
...
```

In `config.ru`, add these lines.

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
map SampleApplication::Application.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
  run Rails.application
end
```

In `production.rb`, add below line.

```
# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server  
config.action_controller.asset_host = "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/main"

# ActionMailer Config
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    :host => "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME",
    :only_path => false,
    :script_name =>  "/main"
}
```

In nginx configuration file, add these lines

```
location /main {
    alias /var/deploy/sample_application/current/public;
    try_files $uri @main;
}

location @main {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://puma_sample_application;
}
```

Comment: The only_path: false and script_name: 'my_sub_uri'  are the keys for rails ActionMailer generating the correct URLs from the helpers.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not configure rails app at all.
In fact you can just change your nginx config.

It should proxy root domain requests to your wordpress app, and subdomain requests to your rails app.

Check out this question, to get config of nginx [How configure nginx for rails app as subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898518/how-configure-nginx-for-rails-app-as-subdomain)